# Reading dates from filenames

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I want to extract dates from the suffixes of files in a particular folder. The contents of such a folder look something like:

```
Packed_Folder_1_2016.06.10
Packed_Folder_1_2016.08.06
Packed_Folder_1_2015.09.03
packed_Folder_1_2015.01.08
... (so on and so forth, always in the same path just different suffixes)
```

There is no pattern to the dates. I need to make a VS form (2013) to read the name of the files and store the date differences.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question pretty extensively to make it shorter and properly formatted. Feel free to revert the change if I misunderstood what you were asking.

Comment: Thank you, that is correct and explained better

Answer (score 0):

Notice how the filenames always follow a pattern? It's always `Packed_Folder_1_####.##.##`, where the last part is a date.

So what you want to do is list the file names in the folder, and try to find a file that matches the pattern. You could use a regular expression to match the filename (it would be something like `R"(Packed_Folder_1_\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})"`).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer,
I wonder,
How will I be able to store the last part of the pattern as a string so that I can reference it later,
A single word or path I am familiar with but as I've never seen the code you have written I am lost with how to store the variable.         The reason I ask is because there will be 20 of the files all with the same ending, I will need to use that string later, this part is to work out what that last part is.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about Forms, so I am assuming you are able to use Visual C++. If that is the case, you can check [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) Class.

You instantiated it with a given path ( file or directory ), and it will trigger events based on some changes on the target (simple change, creation, **rename**  - you can select which one). You could then update your reference, in case its change suits your needs.